# Report stolen documentation

Tags: support, documentation

Where can we report stolen documentation code / text like the following?

The user submitted his examples later, taken what had been already written by earlier proposals, and has been accepted over an older submit, when he should have just accepted and edited it if he felt like it was missing something.

[image: image description here]

[Link to earliest text submit](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/21352?draftId=19874)

[image]

[Link to latest text submit](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/27343)

Comment: I feel your pain when someone posts an answer *after* me with almost the *same* code and *they* get all the rep, upvotes, and the accept. =(

Comment: @JonathanLam there's no "accept" concept in Docs...

Comment: @Braiam I meant the feeling when someone steals your answer in regular Q&A. It's not fun.

Comment: I've encountered this before and it really hurts that people nullify the earlier rejection with an acceptable of the change. It ticks me off sometimes.

Comment: This documentation thing is a mess, copy paste docs from official docs, change bits here and there, farm free rep.. rip Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 7):

First off, I think it's a bit of a stretch to call what happened in your example "stealing". They both fill in the default examples the system creates for a new topic, and as a result they both contain roughly the same information...

...and that's where the similarities end. The structure is different, the actual *text* is different, and from what I can see the edit that survived is actually rather more complete than the one which was rejected. As with "Fastest Gun" answers to simple questions in Q&A, expecting documentation of the basics for a tag to *not* be at all similar is naive; such topics will no doubt often attract those who know the basics by heart and can write them out quickly.

### On plagiarism and wholesale copying of other's work

To the broader topic of one editor copying another's work without attribution (or simply without adding anything of their own to it): please flag and report this.

[image: the little flag icon above each example or topic, and associated dialog]

Remember to include a link to wherever the text was copied from! Someone (another user, a moderator, or staff) will review this and remove the topic / example if need-be.